# Sending multiple instances of NSData with 'CBPeripheralManager' fails after first send

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, bluetooth, xcode6

So I have this code set up:

```
for (int index = 0; index < [dataArray count]; index++) {
    dataToSend = [dataArray objectAtIndex:index];

    BOOL sent = [self.manager updateValue:dataToSend
                      forCharacteristic:(CBMutableCharacteristic *)self.cashierCarachteristic
                   onSubscribedCentrals:nil];

    if (!sent) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to send :(");
    }
}
```

My problem with this however is the fact that, after the first piece of NSData from the array is sent, all the subsequent sends fail. I always get this:

2014-10-24 17:01:45.162 Pengoo[1957:60b] Sending Data: 94

2014-10-24 17:01:45.164 Pengoo[1957:60b] Sending Data: 94

2014-10-24 17:01:45.166 Pengoo[1957:60b] Failed to send :(

2014-10-24 17:01:45.167 Pengoo[1957:60b] Sending Data: 94

2014-10-24 17:01:45.168 Pengoo[1957:60b] Failed to send :(

2014-10-24 17:01:45.169 Pengoo[1957:60b] Sending Data: 94

2014-10-24 17:01:45.170 Pengoo[1957:60b] Failed to send :(

Can anyone tell me why this is? Am I potentially setting up my manager wrong or is this a limitation with *CBPeripheralManager* or...?

Thanks in advance everyone :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have implemented it in one of my apps with a simple queue.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* queue;
```

...

```
- (void) updateAllCharacteristics {
    @synchronized(self.queue)
        if (self.queue == nil) {
            self.queue = [NSMutableArray new];
        }
    }
    for (CBMutableCharacteristic* characteristic in self.service.characteristics) {
        NSString* newCharacteristicValue = [self getNewValueForCharacteristic:characteristic];;
        @synchronized(self.queue) {
            [self.queue addObject:@{ @"characteristic": characteristic, @"value": newCharacteristicValue }];
        }
    }
    [self processCharacteristicsUpdateQueue];
}

- (BOOL)updateCharacteristic:(CBMutableCharacteristic*)characteristic withValue:(NSString*) value {
    NSData* data = [value dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return [self.peripheralManager updateValue:data forCharacteristic:characteristic onSubscribedCentrals:nil];
}

- (void)processCharacteristicsUpdateQueue {
    NSDictionary* characteristicData = [self.queue firstObject];
    if (characteristicData != nil) {
        while ([self updateCharacteristic:characteristicData[@"characteristic"] withValue:characteristicData[@"value"]]) {
            @synchronized(self.queue) {
                [self.queue removeObjectAtIndex:0];
            }
            characteristicData = [self.queue firstObject];
            if (characteristicData == nil) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)peripheralManagerIsReadyToUpdateSubscribers:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral {
    [self processCharacteristicsUpdateQueue];
}
```

now you have to modify the code to adapt it to your app and call the updateAllCharacteristics method.

NOTE: Be sure to set the delegate of the peripheralManager to this class where you put this into

Answer (score 6):

Refer to the [CBPeripheralManager documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheralManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CBPeripheralManager/updateValue:forCharacteristic:onSubscribedCentrals:) -

> **Discussion**
> You use this method to send updates of a characteristic’s
> value—through a notification or indication—to selected centrals that
> have subscribed to that characteristic’s value.
>
> If the method returns
> NO because the underlying transmit queue is full, the peripheral
> manager calls the peripheralManagerIsReadyToUpdateSubscribers: method
> of its delegate object when more space in the transmit queue becomes
> available. After this delegate method is called, you may resend the
> update.

Essentially the Bluetooth hardware transmits at a finite rate and has a finite input buffer and both of these are relatively small compared to the execution speed of the device - so it is possible for your application to rapidly generate more data than the hardware can process.

When `updateValue` returns NO you need to queue your transmit requests and restart transmission until after the `peripheralManagerIsReadyToUpdateSubscribers:` delegate method is called.  You can then resume transmission until it again returns false

Comment: Oops! My bad. I skimmed that part thinking it was unnecessary. Thanks for the help stranger! I'll be sure to read the documentation more thoroughly next time :)

Comment: @Paulw11, Can I have multiple `CBPeripheralManager` in one screen to broadcast 2 different beacons? right now this scenario does not seem to be working. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi.  Perhaps you should ask a new question with more detail; it isn't clear what you are trying to do from your comment.  Multiple CBPeripheral manager's won't change the overall BLE throughput; that is a hardware/radio limitation.

Answer (score 1):

#### Swift 4.0

**Answer from Erhard Dinhobl**

```
struct SendingDataInfo {
    var characterist: CBCharacteristic
    var data: Data
    var centrals: [CBCentral]?
}

var sendingDataInfos = [SendingDataInfo]()
let lockQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.test.LockQueue")

var theCBPeripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)

func updateAllCharacteristics() {
    let fakeData = [SendingDataInfo]()  // Change to your data
    for sendingDataInfo in fakeData {
        lockQueue.sync() {
            let temp = SendingDataInfo(characterist: sendingDataInfo.characterist, data: sendingDataInfo.data, centrals: sendingDataInfo.centrals)
            sendingDataInfos.append(temp)
        }
    }
    processCharacteristicsUpdateQueue()
}

func updateCharacteristic(_ characteristicData: SendingDataInfo) -> Bool {
    return theCBPeripheralManager.updateValue(characteristicData.data, for: characteristicData.characterist as! CBMutableCharacteristic, onSubscribedCentrals: characteristicData.centrals)
}

func processCharacteristicsUpdateQueue() {
    guard let characteristicData = sendingDataInfos.first else {
        return
    }
    while updateCharacteristic(characteristicData) {
        lockQueue.sync() {
            _ = sendingDataInfos.remove(at: 0)
            if sendingDataInfos.first == nil {
                return
            }
        }
    }
}

func peripheralManagerIsReady(toUpdateSubscribers peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
    processCharacteristicsUpdateQueue()
}
```

now you have to modify the code to adapt it to your app and call the updateAllCharacteristics method.

**NOTE: Be sure to set the delegate of the peripheralManager to this class where you put this into**